What is this no-livery, fully white plane parked at Mumbai airport?

At the center of this picture, there is a white plane with a blank livery.
To me, this plane looks like an Airbus A310. First I thought it was an A330, but then this plane doesn't have winglets, and it looks too "compressed" (I couldn't get a better word) to be an A330.
If it is actually an A310, that's very rare at Mumbai airport.
It is parked in the international cargo area, near the FedEx 777 and National Airlines 747.
I already did Google Image search, and that said it was an A330-300, but I doubt that.
Cropped pic of just the plane:

More than the plane model, I'm interested in the operator and from where it came.

After doing some digging around on FlightRadar24 with the replay function, I was able to find out that this plane in the picture is an Airbus A300-600, which was converted to a freighter in 2005.
It currently has the registration "ER-BUS" and came to Mumbai from Al Ain International Airport in UAE, being operated by "Fly Pro", a cargo company registered in Moldova.
It's 34 years old and has no livery.

(Source)

Nice research!  It is literally a white-box airframe.

Nice research, well done!

I'm expecting Nicolas Cage to inspect cargo

"ER-BUS" ^^, I see what they did there

Some additional info from Planespotters: delivered new to EgyptAir in 1990, converted to cargo in 2005, flew with EgyptAir Cargo until 2019, taken over by Fly Pro in 2023. Fly Pro also flies three 747s, but only owns one of them, and that one is also all-white.

It is very clearly an Airbus A300 to me.
Although the A300 and A310 are similar, there are recognisable differences.


The wingtip are A300 style, not A310.
I count 4 flap track fairings underneath the wing outside of the engine. That is consistent with the A300; the A310 features only 3 flap track fairings on that wing section.

I haven't been able to find out which A300 it is yet.

This is really quite common in cargo carriers, especially those that might rent aircraft for short periods of time - it's often not worth painting a livery.
Some of the fleet for AMX AIr appear completely white and the same for many of Smartlynx Airlines

So you are saying it's either a 767 or an A321?

There's no way that the plane is either of those. Unless you've got a clear shot of the registration number it is going to be extremely difficult to identify an airline, if not impossible. It probably is an A300, though.

@IsraelO.Emmanuel yeah it's gonna be hard to identify the airline, but I think the make and model should be possible to discern
